# Scale <img> within parent div that wraps around it

Tags: html, css, lightbox

I cannot get this sorted out. I found some answers that come close but never perfect.

I made a lightbox that is hidden and can be activated by clicking thumbnails. This opens the lightbox which I would like to have at a max of 85%.The  within has to scale to accept this.

Here's the lightbox buildup.

```
> <div class="lightbox" id="1">   <div class="box">     <a class="close"
> href="#"><img src="img/closebtn.jpg" /></a>
>     <p class="title">img1</p>
>     <a class="nav" href="#2">Next</a>
>     <div class="content">
>       <img src="img/img1.jpg"> 
>         <p class="desc">Description text</p>
>     </div>
>     <div class="clear"></div>   </div> </div>
```

And it's styling.

```
.lightbox {
    /** Hide the lightbox */
    display: none;

    /** Apply basic lightbox styling */
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    color:#333333;
    }


.lightbox:target {
    /** Show lightbox when it is target **/
    display: block;
    outline: none;
}


.lightbox .content img {
}


.lightbox .box {
    width: -webkit-min-content;
    width: -moz-min-content;
    width: min-content;
    margin: 2% auto;
    padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 26px -3px #777777;
    }

.lightbox .title {
    margin:0;
    margin:17px 0 0 0;
    border-bottom:1px #ccc solid;
    font-size:22px;
    color:#666;
    float:left;
    }


.lightbox .content {
    color:#333;
    }

.lightbox .close {
    float:right;
    margin:8px 0;
}

.lightbox .desc{
    margin:30px 0 15px 0;
}

.lightbox .box .nav{
    color:#666;
    font-size:22px;
    float:right;
    margin:17px 20px 0 0;
}
```

With this, the box wraps around the image nicely, but the image doesn't get scaled yet.

Comment: Did you copy this correctly?

.lightbox .content img {
}

Answer (score 0):

You should add styles to images:

```
img {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Or maybe just the one you need (I see it doesn't have any code in it yet):

```
.lightbox .content img {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes, what this does is scale the image to 100% of its parent. But this makes the parent wrap around the image of the close button and the content tekst so results in a very very small wrapper with an even smaller image in it. Adding width:85% to the wrapper doesn't seem to have any effect.